# Generating comma separated input for LCM

Tags: functions, core-language

I would like to calculate the Least Common Multiple of the 100 first numbers.
I've tried with

```
LCM[Table[i, {i, 10}]]
```

But it produces a list instead of the right answer, a single number.

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
> ```

It seems that `LCM` doesn't like to get a list as the input.

What's the proper way to do it?

Comment: `LCM` takes a `Sequence` of numbers (not a `List` of numbers as input. Use `LCM @@ Table[i, {i, 100}]`? or `LCM[Sequence @@ Table[i, {i, 100}]]`.

Comment: just posted the comment as an answer along with few additional ways to use a list as input to  `LCM`.

Comment: Related LCM & GCD demonstration http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/UnderstandingTheLeastCommonMultipleAndGreatestCommonDivisor/

Comment: @kglr `Apply[LCM,Range[100]]` works as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LCM](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LCM.html) takes a `Sequence` of numbers (not a `List` of numbers) as input.

```
input = Table[i, {i, 100}];
```

You can use `input` in `LCM` in a number of ways:

```
LCM @@ input (* replace the `Head` of `input` by `LCM` *)
LCM[Sequence@@input] (* replace the `Head` of `input` by `Sequence` *)
input /. List -> LCM
input2 = input; ReplacePart[input2, 0 -> LCM]
input3 = input; input3[[0]]=LCM; input3
input4 = input; MapAt[LCM &, input4, {0}]
```

all give

```
69720375229712477164533808935312303556800
```

Comment: What's the most efficient?

Comment: @skan, not sure ... as far as i can tell, it seems they are more or less the same speedwise.

Comment: and memorywise?

Comment: @skan, good question; i am afraid i don't know. By the way, you don't need to make copies of `input` to make use of  the last 3 methods, you can make the replacements in-place.